# Share Wi-Fi Internet access via Bluetooth on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have tried multiple ways I got on Google, without luck.

BlueMan based apporaches will NOT work because my Pi does NOT have X running. I would like to solve this just using BlueZ and some simple scripts if necessary.

My Raspberry Pi runs Raspbian. My BlueZ is version 4.99. `hcid.conf` is NOT found in `/etc/bluetooth`. `pand` has been installed but I cannot see any new interface related to Bluetooth added to `ifconfig` results.

My idea is that, I should be able to create a virtual interface into `ifconfig` results, and manage it with a static IP address defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Then I can run normal IP forwarding etc. I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, but so far I cannot find anything new in results of `ifconfig`.

A lot of articles I found use bridge. I'd prefer NAT if possible. Because I don't think bridges work for Wi-Fi interfaces. I already have a Wi-Fi to Wi-Fi forwarding NAT configured on this Pi, therefore, once I can connect a device to a virtual interface on Pi, the rest should be trivial, I think.

Comment: This belongs in the Raspi Beta page.

Comment: I'd have to question why you want to do it this way? Bluetooth configuration outside the simple connections is hard and unreliable in my experience.

Comment: @BiTinerary I am afraid if I do that, they will tell me this question is not Raspberry Pi specific. I think the same question applies to any Debian based Linux distribution.

Comment: @JulianKnight What do you mean by "simple connections"?

Comment: @JulianKnight I want to do this because I know I can achieve the same functionality on Ubuntu using BlueMan. However I cannot find a terminal-only solution because as far as I know, BlueMan is graphic. I am not sure what BlueMan has done to my Bluetooth configurations...

Comment: What I meant was anything outside what the GUI tools give you. I've been trying to work with BTLE for example for an automation project and found the whole thing utterly impenetrable & connections that should work simply don't.